# Phpexcel fill in empty cells

Tags: php, loops, phpexcel

I would like to fill in the empty spaces of a csv column and its in one column using phpexcel I have added a demo for your viewing: The flow check B2 is its not empty go the next B3 if B3 is empty take value from B2.

Here is my attempt could put my code snip but i have posted the same post with a demo and my attemp.

[PHP Excel fill in Empty Cells.](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/438892/phpexcel-fill-in-empty-cells#post1886143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel doesn't provide any built-in function for this: it will only change the content of a cell if you explicitly tell it to do so. You'll need to iterate through the worksheet testing for cells that contain a NULL or empty string, and populate them with the value that you want before saving to CSV.

Something like:

```
for ($i=2;$i<$highestRow;$i++) {
    $colB = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getValue();
    if ($colB == NULL || $colB == '') {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
            'B'.$i, 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.($i-1))->getValue();
        );
    }
}
```